# Tensorflow object detection in C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow, object-detection

I've been training object detection models in the last few days mainly with tensorflow and yolov3.
Projects:

- [Tensorflow GPU object detection models](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10)
- [TensorFlow2.x-YOLOv3](https://github.com/YunYang1994/TensorFlow2.0-Examples/tree/master/4-Object_Detection/YOLOV3)

I wanted to know if there is any guide to use these models trained whit Python export them and insert these models on other project in C++ since I need to consult them from another project in this language.
Everything I've seen in Google is obsolete or gives me a lot of problems because of complexity.

I have no problem about using other models if it is quick, I need low ms of processing because it is for a quality control production line.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

[Tensorflow Serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker) provides HTTP REST and gPRC APIs for using trained models without any conversion. I used it in Java-based project, but you can use it in C++ as well (Tensorflow Serving is written in C++, by the way).

Comment: I thought about it, but I think it would be a bit slow because I would have to save the image and perform the query and receive the answer, I need times around 50 ms.

Comment: 50 ms latency is tough task, but I think might be achievable if you're dealing with small images and if your project runs on the same machine with TF Serving.